# Procees form no working well

Tags: forms, jquery

I am trying to send this form, but this does not work

**The processor in jquery :**

```
  function processorform(id)
{

jQuery(function() 
{
var $ = jQuery;             
$('.sp-poll-'+id+' form').submit(formProcess);


function formProcess(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var poll    = $('input[name=poll]').val(),
answer  = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val(),
div     = $(this).parent(),
action  = $(this).attr('action');



}


}
```

**The HTML code**

```
    <div class="sp-poll-1">
    <form method="post" action="include/submit.php" class="format" onsubmit="processorform('1');">
<input type="hidden" name="poll" value="<?php echo $pollid; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="backurl" value="<?php echo $thisPage; ?>"/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="poll-<?php echo $pollid; ?>-<?php echo $key; ?>" class="sp-input-radio" />
<input type="submit" class="sp-btn" value="<?php _e('Send'); ?>"/></p>

    </form>
    </div>
```

When I try to send the form, it never works and always goes to submit.php and doesn't show the div results. I don´t know what´s wrong with the code or what the fix might be.

Thank´s for the help.

Comment: Where's your updatePoll method?

Comment: I put now but this other script only for update form no for process it

Comment: I can't tell where your variable is coming from `url: spAjax.url,`.  Try changing this to `url: action,`.

Comment: correct your code : in slideUp add `)` after the closing bracket `}`

Comment: No important that part i put ok all code here you can see , thank´s

Answer (score 0):

If you change this line:

```
onsubmit="processorform('1');"
```

to this:

```
onsubmit="processorform('1');return false;"
```

You won't go to submit.php.

But since you're using AJAX to post your request, some other errors may appear, since we don't have all the varibles to check if it will work.

Comment: No works always go direct to the submit , i don´t know which it´s the error , really

Comment: Again: the main problem relies on your AJAX code. Since you're using jQuery to post your data via AJAX you don't even need the action tag on your form. But just removing it won't fix it. You have to understand how this stuff works before fooling around it.

Comment: If no put action how send the form , always use action with plugins of jquery for send forms , how indicate the file where you go submit the form for save results ?

Comment: Remember this 'url: spAjax.url'? this is where your AJAX script will send the data. So, like asked before, what is the value of spAjax.url variable?